# Making a request to auth API endpoint from angular 8 app results in a CORS error while the same request from Postman works perfectly file

Tags: angular, cors, http-headers

I am making a http POST request from an angular 8 app (which is running on localhost) to an auth API endpoint to which I have no access. I need to get a token from this endpoint to validate the user. The request is shown below

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        })
    };

    const body = new HttpParams()
        .set('grant_type', 'password')
        .set('username', username)
        .set('password', password);

    return this.http.post<any>(`https://api-url`, body, httpOptions)
        .pipe(map(user => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            if (user && user.access_token) {
                // Work with user details
            }

            return user;
        }));
}
```

I get an error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api-url' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

When I make the same request from Postman, it works perfectly and I get the response from that endpoint with a token. I don't exactly know what is causing the issue. My screenshots from postman request are shown below. Please help me out with this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using identity server 4?

Comment: I don't know what is being used on the API side. It is an external one given to me and I only have control on the client side.

Comment: What is the Authorization type? Basic?

Comment: The Authorization type I am using in postman is 'Inherit auth from parent'. Do I need to setup anything related to Authorization when I am making the request from the app? The endpoint was given to me and was mentioned that it is a public endpoint and a POST request has to be made as mentioned above to get the token.

Comment: Are you using a postman collection? Can you show me you Post man screen?

Comment: Since this is a resource owner password mechanism there must be a Client ID and a Client secret. Ask anyone who knows about the API.

Comment: I added screenshots from my postman screens. I am not using postman collection. I did not send any Client ID or Client secret in the postman request

Comment: Any luck? Did you ask from any one who knows about API?

Comment: The ones who gave me the API link are not available at the moment. I am sorry to ask but are you sure there is no fix for this from client side?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205785/discussion-between-binara-thambugala-and-suvenk).

Answer (score -1):

you should try using an interceptor
[Refer this](https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-interceptors/)

if it doesn't work and you're using chrome as your browser then try this in Run. maybe your back-end hasn't changed CROS properties to receive data from all origins.

```
`chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security`
```